# Check DateTime is valid in Linq Where clause

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

How do i check in my linq where clause if the date is valid and then query on the valid date ? I've tried this but it throws an error on the invalid dates.

```
var dates = new List<string>();
    dates.Add("21/11/2016");
    dates.Add("25/10/1975");
    dates.Add("31/2/2016");
    dates.Add("asdad");
    dates.Add("");
            
    var validDates = dates.Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x) < DateTime.Today).ToList();
```

or this but it returns no results

```
DateTime isValid;
var validDates = dates.Where(x => DateTime.TryParse(x, out isValid) && DateTime.Parse(x) < DateTime.Today).ToList();
```

Comment: That's because those aren't valid DateTime formats for the default `TryParse`. Check out [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bFCICx) demo which shows that they aren't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try providing *explicit* format with a help of `TryParseExact`:

```
var validDates = dates
  .Where(s => DateTime.TryParseExact(
                  s, 
                 "d/M/yyyy", 
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                  DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
                  out var date) && 
              date < DateTime.Today)
  .ToList();
```

Note, that there's no need to parse *twice*: you can use the outcome (`date`) of the `TryParse` to test with `DateTime.Today`.